# I recommend that "Company X adopt" vs "Company X adopts"

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement, subjunctive-mood, collective-nouns

What is the correct verb form to use here?

> I recommend that Company X adopt Y.

or

> I recommend that Company X adopts Y.

Answer (score 1):

Recommend takes Subjunctive, so the verb is in the infinitve:
I recommend that Company X adopt Y.
http://englishplus.com/grammar/00000031.htm
He recommended that each driver report his tips.

Comment: This somewhat differs from BrEng to AmEng, where the former usually prefers a modal verb, especially 'should', whilst the latter prefers to use the infinitive. I myself would use both, depending on circumstance.

Comment: @Deonyi are you suggesting that BrEngs would prefer 'I recommend that Company X **should adopt** Y'?

Comment: @568ml Yes, I would personally use the infinitive for 'recommend', but use 'should adopt' for 'suggest'. Again, BrEng to my knowledge uses both, but uses the subjunctive less often.

Comment: @Deonyi  The report recommends that tourists avoid the region. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/essential-british-english/recommend

Comment: @Cathy Gartaganis Perhaps I wasn't clear. Whilst the subjunctive should be used in that situation, _informally_, usually the indicative would be used instead in BrEng. http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/words/when-to-use-the-subjunctive

Comment: @Deonyi Of course. I assumed the question pertained to business English because of the content, and therefore provided the formal grammatical construction.